# ___tmp___/punish? in response

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, web-crawler

I am trying to get responses from a website for some work, the url is [link](https://www.lazada.com.my/catalog/?q=watch&_keyori=ss&from=input&ajax=1)

On running the python script , for the first time i am getting the response, but on running again getting some weird response like

```
    {
  "rgv587_flag": "sm", 
  "url": "https://www.lazada.com.my:443//catalog/_____tmd_____/punish?x5secdata=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&x5step=2&ajax=true&fliggy_async=true"
}
```

I tried changing the network and even tried vpn, but no fruitful result. I am curious what is this. I can see similar responses from some chinese websites, is this some sort of technique to prevent scraping. It will be very helpful if i could get some information on this